# With the new r_liteprofile is it possible to know the authenticated user's LinkedIn profile URL?

Tags: linkedin-api

We're using Sign in with LinkedIn, which is deprecating the r_basicprofile scope that offered the profile URL. I don't see a way to get this information using the new r_liteprofile scope. Was that intentionally left out? It seems odd that LinkedIn wouldn't want to drive people back to their own site.

Answer (score 1):

Deadlock :) or just changes of LinkedIn policies.

According this tiny article [Public Profile Url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api#public-profile-url) you have to use **vanityName** which is available from **r_basicprofile** which is not going to be deprecated but available only for Enterprise LinkedIn users :(

Quoting from [Self-Serve v1 to v2 API Migration Frequently Asked Questions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context):

> Looking to maintain access to the Basic Profile fields? [Learn more](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/products)
>   about LinkedIn Developer Enterprise products.

Comment: What do you mean under "Enterprise LinkedIn users" ? How to apply in order to be able to get r_basicprofile and user vanityName  now?

Comment: That is what I meant by "Deadlock". It is not clear from their docs how you can apply. The link provided above has some Enterprise products and I guess accessing/applying for some of them might give you an access :(

Comment: We are struggling with the same issue. The developer part of their website is very buggy. You can't verify your apps. We are struggling to get enterprise products.